# Wordpress + Visual Composer Parallax Scrolling

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have added visual composer plugin in wordpress and added parallax scrolling sections with image background. I have 5 navigation menu items in which "Contact" is the last one.When i click on contact, it's not scrolling to the section. Why is this happening?Please help.

Answer (score 0):

check the scroll speed options within the row settings, turn it up to about 5.0-6.0 for a more visual scroll effect.